# How to accommodate holiday effects to weekly data?

Tags: r, facebook-prophet

I am using Facebook-prophet algorithm for weekly sales forecast, i have data captured at weekly level. I would like to use the option of holiday effects the algorithm provides. How do i apply it for weekly data?
I am looking for suggestions, i am not providing any data or code.I use R language

Thanks

Comment: There are couple of options, 1) get thee holiday data from the package, 2) create a holiday data.frame with 'ds', 'holiday', lower.window, upper.window specifying the custom window values.  However, it makes sense to include holidays for daily data instead of weekly as the effect would not be that much

Comment: @akrun: you mean though the data is at weekly level , if we just specify holiday dates then algorithm can automatically pick up spikes in weekly data due to holidays?

Comment: You can check whether including the holidays have any effect on the weekly data

Comment: @akrun also how would i extend the algorithm for batch forecasting ? I have multiple  time series

Comment: You can ask these questions in crossvalidated rather than SO

Answer (score 0):

From the official prophet documentation :

Holiday effects are applied to the particular date on which the holiday was specified. With data that has been aggregated to weekly or monthly frequency, holidays that don’t fall on the particular date used in the data will be ignored: for example, a Monday holiday in a weekly time series where each data point is on a Sunday. To include holiday effects in the model, the holiday will need to be moved to the date in the history dataframe for which the effect is desired.